# codeigniter url slug & pagination make duplicate content

Tags: codeigniter, friendly-url, codeigniter-url

**My pagination url work at:**

```
checkout.gr/home/index/4
```

and my webmaster tool see duplicate content for meta description & keywords for page

```
checkout.gr/home/index/4
checkout.gr/home/index/
```

and all pagination list…

**And final i make slug article for friendly seo url but now my article work with 2 url example:**

*first url without slug*

```
checkout.gr/magazine/index/3
```

*ulr with slug*

```
checkout.gr/magazine/index/3/to-penintaraki-byronas
```

and make again duplicate content again…

How can i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

This is normal, you can counteract this behaviour in a number of different ways. Like a 301 redirect, sitemaps,...

you can find some more detailed information on this page (watch out, some solutions mentioned here are only relevant to google)

https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en